# How to call json.decode()?

Tags: python, json, decode, typeerror, attributeerror

The code I am working on is a function that converts a JSON object into iCalendar form.  To do this, I am writing an iCalendar template, and then inserting the info from the JSON into that.  My code requires JSON's decode which has caused me a lot of setbacks lately.  Here is what I have tried and the error messages I am getting.

```
import json
def convert(jsonData)
    ....
    data = json.decode(jsonData)
```

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'decode'

This error confuses me because the method is in the JSON API https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#module-json

```
import json
def convert(jsonData)
    ....
    data = json.JSONDecoder().decode(jsonData)
```

TypeError: expected string or buffer

The second error references a line of code in decode():
line 366

```
end = self.raw_decode(s,idx=_w(s,o).end())
```

**EDIT**:

```
data = json.JSONDecoder.decode(jsonData)
```

TypeError: unbound method decode() must be called with JSONDecoder instance as first argument (got dict instance instead)

Comment: what is the type of jsonData?

Comment: If you read through the docs you linked, you'd see that `decode()` is a method of a `json.JSONDecoder` object...

Comment: what about `json.load()` or `json.loads()`?

Comment: I should have mentioned, I tried created an object of JSONDecoder but that did not work either. @MattDMo

Comment: The type of jsonData is a u'string @JulienSpronck

Comment: @EmmyD: Using `json.JSONDecoder().decode(jsonData)` works if `jsonData` is a string..

Answer (score 1):

If `jsonData` is a string, you just need `json.loads(jsonData)` to convert it to a Python object.